# How to print calendar for whole year (2019)

Tags: python, calendar

I am trying to print the whole calendar for the year 2019. I am able to print the calendar but I want to print the year in front of all the months like:

```
January 2019
```

But the output is like:

```
2019

January
```

This is my code:

```
import calendar

def printcalendar(year):
     print(calendar.calendar(2019,1,1,1,1))

year = 2019
printcalendar(year)
```

Comment: read documentation for [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html). There should be information how to create own class with own methods which format text.

Comment: @furas. This is non-trivial based on said documentation.

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 2):

Since the calendar is well structured, you can write your own function to format it how you want. Your function should accomplish the following tasks:

1. Remove the year at the beginning of the string
2. Remove the extra new lines that used to be between the year and January
3. Replace each month with the month + the year
4. Print the result

This is easy enough.

```py
import calendar

def print_calendar(year):
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    cal_string = calendar.calendar(year, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    cal_string = cal_string.strip() # Removes the leading and trailing whitespaces
    cal_string = cal_string.replace(str(year), "") # Removes all occurences of the year
    cal_string = cal_string[2:] # Removes the extra newlines at the beginning
    for month in months:
        cal_string = cal_string.replace(f"  {month}", f"{month} {year}") # Replaces each month with the month and the year. 
        # We added the two spaces before month so that it's centered
    print(cal_string)
    return

print_calendar(2019)
```

Output:

```
    January 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31

    February 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
... and so on
```

**Edit**: `f-strings` were introduced in Python 3.6. If you are using a version of python before this, you have to replace the line reading

```py
cal_string = cal_string.replace(f"  {month}", f"{month} {year}") # Replaces each month with the month and the year.
```

with

```py
cal_string = cal_string.replace("  {}".format(month), "{} {}".format(month, year)) # Replaces each month with the month and the year.
```

Comment: cal_string = cal_string.replace(f"{month}", f"{month} {year}") # Replaces each month with the month and the year.
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `f-strings` were introduced in python 3.6. What version of python are you using?

Comment: this will fail for python < 3.6. See my answer

Comment: It will not if you read the edit i made several minutes before your comment, and also several minutes before you claimed my answer would fail into your answer.

Comment: see my answer and let me know for which case it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `print(calendar.__file__)` you can see path to file with source code for this module.

To display month name it uses code

```
class TextCalendar(Calendar):

    def formatmonthname(self, theyear, themonth, width, withyear=True):
        """
        Return a formatted month name.
        """
        s = month_name[themonth]
        if withyear:
            s = "%s %r" % (s, theyear)
        return s.center(width)
```

and it uses `withyear=` to decide if it should display year.

---

If I create own class without `if withyear:` then it will always print year.

I had to also add `calendar.` to `calendar.month_name`

```
import calendar 

class MyCalendar(calendar.TextCalendar):

    def formatmonthname(self, theyear, themonth, width, withyear=True):
        s = calendar.month_name[themonth]
        s = "%s %r" % (s, theyear)
        return s.center(width)

c = MyCalendar()

print(c.formatyear(2019,1,1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works **regardless** of the python version.

@SyntaxVoisupportsMonica's solution will fail for any python < 3.6.

---

**This solution will print whatever month you want i.e. if `m=[5]` it will print May.**

---

**Conclusion. Use this:**

```
import calendar

def mymonth(y,m):
    for i in m:
        print(calendar.month(y,i))


# second argument should be a list
mymonth(2019, [5,6])
```

Prints:

```
      May 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31

     June 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Nice and short. It looks like the contents of your `m`-list don't matter. I could naiively assume `mymonth(2019, [5,6,7])` would print months 5, 6, and 7 but it would only print months 1, 2, and 3. I think it could be `for month in m: print(calendar.month(y, month))` instead

Comment: Not yet. `mymonth(2019,[5, 6])` still only prints January and February.

Comment: You don't even need to enumerate `m`. You don't use the index, `i` at all.

Comment: Yes I have updated into the last version. This works fine